# Setting SCNNode's rotation with valid values, but it's always 0,0,0,0

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, scenekit, scnnode

I'm trying to set my camera node's rotation, and the value's are there, but it never changes from 0,0,0,0...
initialize the player node (left out other settings, the node has no geometry, but its physics body does have geometry)

```
playerNode = [SCNNode node];
```

and I set it's position and add it to the scene's root node...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create a new scene
    SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene scene];
    scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0, -9, 0);
    scene.physicsWorld.timeStep = 1.0/360;

    // add world node
    worldNode = [SCNNode node];
    worldNode.name = @"world";
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:worldNode];

    // add terrain
    .../* terrain stuff */

    // add player node
    playerNode = [SCNNode node];
    playerNode.name = @"player";
    playerNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
    playerNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic shape:[SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:[SCNCylinder cylinderWithRadius:0.2 height:1] options:nil]];
    playerNode.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.9999;
    playerNode.physicsBody.damping = 0.9999;
    playerNode.physicsBody.rollingFriction = 0;
    playerNode.physicsBody.friction = 0;
    playerNode.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
    playerNode.physicsBody.velocityFactor = SCNVector3Make(1, 0, 1);
    playerNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:playerNode];

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
    [playerNode addChildNode:cameraNode];

    cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
    cameraNode.camera.xFov = 53;
    cameraNode.camera.zNear = 0.01;
    cameraNode.camera.zFar = 5000;
    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
    .../* rest of view did load */
}
```

and then trying to set the rotation:

```
-(void)lookGestureRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    SCNView *scnView = (SCNView *)self.view;
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"lookGestureRecognized: translation x %g y %g", translation.x, translation.y);
    CGFloat hAngle = acos(((float)translation.x / 200) - (float)M_PI_2);
    CGFloat vAngle = acos(((float)translation.y / 200) - (float)M_PI_2);

    // rotate hero
    [playerNode.physicsBody applyTorque:SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, hAngle) impulse:YES];

    // tilt camera
    [SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:0.0];
    elevation = MAX((float)-M_PI_4, MIN((float)M_PI_4, elevation + vAngle));
    NSLog(@"elevation: %g", elevation);
    SCNVector4 cameraRotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, elevation);
    cameraNode.rotation = cameraRotation;
    // cameraNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(cameraNode.transform, 1, 0, 0, elevation); // tried this, didn't work either
    NSLog(@"cameraNode.rotation = x %g y %g z %g, w %g", cameraNode.rotation.x, cameraNode.rotation.y, cameraNode.rotation.z, cameraNode.rotation.w);

    // reset translation
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
```

the elevation is being calculated correctly, but trying to set it to the node's rotation fails... the log always says 0,0,0,0...

```
NSLog sample output:
2015-02-17 14:37:11.732 usingGestureRecognizer.01[96111:289778] lookGestureRecognized: translation x 0 y 0.5
2015-02-17 14:37:11.733 usingGestureRecognizer.01[96111:289778] elevation: -0.785398
2015-02-17 14:37:11.733 usingGestureRecognizer.01[96111:289778] cameraNode.rotation = x 0 y 0 z 0, w 0
```

Any ideas?

(Side note, mimic'ing the code I found from an example, translated it from swift to obj-c, and the sample code works perfectly)

Comment: I'm not managing to reproduce this. What's happening in between when you create the nodes and when you set the camera rotation? (If they're happening in different methods, which are they?) Which nodes have physics bodies and which kinds of physics bodies do they have?

Comment: @rickster: edited to include node creation and the gestureRecognizer that's being called...

Comment: what happens if you don't set the transaction's duration ? (or begin then commit the transaction)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer? I'm a newb.

The actual answer? Be very careful when copying code from a tutorial... I had declared a private variable SCCNode cameraNode, and was trying to change this node's rotation, however, the actual camera node doing the camera work was declared as a private method variable in viewDidLoad...

So, again, thank you very much for your help guys, this site is invaluable to me, I have learned so much, but I'm personally 0 for 2 asking questions, both of mine have just been MY oversights. Thanks again, sincerely